# How to access a Ruby splat argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, devise, splat

I have overridden the `send_devise_notification` methods from my devise gem.

I need to access the first element in the `*args` array, and I would assume this can be achieved with `*args[0]`.

I am expecting a string, but check out the strange output below:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  protected

    def send_devise_notification(notification, *args)
      p *args.inspect               # => ["auNsGzsnpoQWtAk2Z1Tr", {}]
      p *args[0].inspect            # => "auNsGzsnpoQWtAk2Z1Tr"
      p *args[0].class.to_s.inspect # => "String"
      token = *args[0]
      p token.inspect               # => ["auNsGzsnpoQWtAk2Z1Tr"]
      p token.class.to_s.inspect    # => "Array"
    end
end
```

When I log it, I see a string. But when I put it into a `token` variable I see an array. And I can't convert the variable into a string. I have tried `token.to_s`, etc.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: u can use args.first to get the first element @johnsmith1976 being *args is an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `args` and it's an array:

```
def a(*args)
   args.each {|e| puts "-- #{e}" }
end  

a(1,2,3,4)
#-- 1
#-- 2
#-- 3
#-- 4
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So if you want to get its first element - call `args[0]` or `args.first` (without the leading asterisk).

Comment: Yup, you use unary `*` operator only in method definition and method call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `args.first` to get the first element , being `*args` is an array.